# Bind9 warning on Debian

Tags: linux, debian, bind

I'm running a Bind9 (9.8.4-rpz2+rl005.12-P1) DNS on a Debian 7.9 server and all is working fine, but whenever I try to restart the named service I get the following error into syslog:

**WARNING: key file (/etc/bind/rndc.key) exists, but using default configuration file (/etc/bind/rndc.conf)**

named-checkconf command does not give me any error.

Since I don't want my DNS stop working prior to do anything I would like to have some tips from someone that knows better than me how can I get rid of this warning or if I should ignore this message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The warning is telling you that you *have* an `rndc.key` configuration file (possibly/probably left over from an older version) but it's not being used.  The default configuration file `rndc.conf` is what bind is actually using for its configuration.

Comment: You should do this more often.

Comment: @Iain 1010 to go!  Yay for REMAAS...

Comment: So if I remove or rename the /etc/bind/rndc.key I should get rid of that warning message?

Comment: Yes.  p.s. you can accept this answer if you find it useful by clicking the check mark.

Comment: That'll be just 996 now then.

Comment: Fixed my warning and checked your answer ;-) Thanks!